# How to force submit - Asynchronous code in submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I'm trying to force submitting of my form, the problem is that I use [bootboxjs](http://bootboxjs.com/)
(that uses an asynchronous code) to make a confirmation dialog before submitting, this is exactly I want, also the required inputs are validated in that way.

This is the structure of my JS code:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
  bootbox.confirm({
    message: "Are you sure?",
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            label: 'Yes',
            className: 'btn-danger'
        },
        cancel: {
            label: 'NO, STOP!',
            className: 'btn-primary'
        }
    },
    callback: function (result){
      if (result)
      {
        // Some code to set values to hidden inputs and another irrelevant stuff...
        // The right command (that I didn't know) to force the form
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

How can I avoid this issue and preserve the validation of required inputs?

Comment: could you clarify more the problem !!

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to **force** submit of the form after doing some stuff (please see the JavaScript code in my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the jquery event and use a native one to force a browser default submit when you are ready

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
  // store reference to form due to callback context
  var form = this;

  bootbox.confirm({
    message: "Are you sure?",
    buttons: {... },
    callback: function (result){
      if (result)
      {
        // Some code to set values to hidden inputs and another irrelevant stuff...
        // Now use native submit

         form.submit();
      }
    }
  });
  // prevents jQuery submit only
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I wonder why `$("#myForm").submit();` is not the same of `form.submit();` Could you clarify this, please, I'm curious.

Comment: Because `this` is not a jQuery object...it is the actual element....so you are not using jQuery submit() but native javascript `submit()` which bypasses the jQuery event listener

Comment: great! thanks for the explanation. I know this is offtopic, but do you think someone can learn this kind of thing by reading this book http://eloquentjavascript.net/ ?

Comment: that is a well known book...but in this case it is a bit of a jQuery trick that really comes from experience and deeper understanding of how jQuery works